# No pokestops, no gyms detected in Galaxy S7 Edge and Xperia Z

Tags: pokemon-go

As of now, I am unable to see any Pokéstops, any nearby Pokémon, nor any gyms nearby me(location is highly populated by Pokéstops and gyms). I have Pokémon GO installed on 2 devices and play in 2 different accounts, but the problem is same with both the accounts. I can't see anything other than my avatar, the map, and poke options. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I play on my iphone and go to the same poke-stop/gym every other day.  There this 1 day, nothing show up.  I know it's there and thought the new update had buggered my game.  Anyway, I close my app and re-opened and voila it's there again.  So it's something you might be able to try.

My friend uses the Galaxy s6, she's not good at it and nether am I, I couldn't for the life of me work out how to close apps other than to delete them for her and re-install.